# Get everything between the first character '<' and the last character of '>'

Tags: c#, regex

So i'm trying to get the XML only from this format:

```
--------------------------3cbec9ce8f05
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="owServerData"; filename="details.xml"
Content-Type: text/plain

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Devices-Detail-Response xmlns="http://www.example.com"> 
 // Rest omitted
</Devices-Detail-Response>
------------------------------3cbec9ce8f05--
```

So basically everything after the first < and everything between until the last '>'.

So far i have `.*<(.*)>.*` which only returns `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Thanks!

Expected result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Devices-Detail-Response xmlns="http://www.example.com"> 
 // Rest omitted
</Devices-Detail-Response>
```

Comment: which language?

Comment: @Allan it's for an application in C#

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Ok thanks, for the 

`<Devices-Detail-Response xmlns="http://www.example.com">
 // Rest omitted
</Devices-Detail-Response>` what do you expect as output? also there is a `>` missing after the `xmlns=http://www.example.com"` right?

Comment: @Allan yes, and i edited the post with the expected result

Comment: Thanks I have answered the question ;-) Let me know if it works for you! Regex is not uniform and the syntax, features depend a lot on the language.

Comment: Do you know for sure that the text before and after the XML document does not contain any `<` or `>`?  For example, can the `name` tag contain arbitrary text?

Comment: @EricLippert yes i know for sure, because the data comes from a embedded software, names will not change only the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following regex:

```
<\?xml version="1\.0" encoding="UTF-8"\?>\s*<\s*([^\s]*)(?:.|\s)*<\/\s*\1\s*>
```

**Input:**

```
--------------------------3cbec9ce8f05
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="owServerData"; filename="details.xml"
Content-Type: text/plain

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Devices-Detail-Response xmlns="http://www.example.com"> 
 <device>a</device>
 <info>abc</info>
 <test1><u>123</u><v>456</v><z/></test1>
</Devices-Detail-Response>
------------------------------3cbec9ce8f05--
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Devices-Detail-Response xmlns="http://www.example.com" 
 <device>a</device>
 <info>abc</info>
 <test1><u>123</u><v>456</v><z/></test1>
</Devices-Detail-Response>
```

**demo:** https://regex101.com/r/r6Kbh2/3/

Answer (score 1):

A period, by default, will not match line breaks. You would need to use the `s` modifier.

Also, your first dot is greedy, and it will consume all of your `<` up to the last one that still allows the remaining pattern to match. Instead of using a non-greedy dot `.*?`, I would use a negated character class to match everything except a `<`.

```
/[^<]*<(.*)>.*/s
```

See it on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/LMI2g0/2)

An alternative method would be to use the `\r` (carriage return) and `\n` (newline) characters in a character class:

```
/[^<]*<((?:.|[\r\n])*)>.*/
```

Comment: You didn't tag a language, but JS does support the `s` flag. I'm not overly familiar with regexr.com, but your extended data [works here](https://regex101.com/r/LMI2g0/4)

Comment: Ah, excuse my ignorance, i thought regex was globally the same. I'm using it on a C# application

Comment: See if the update works: `/[^<]*<((?:.|[\r\n])*)>.*/` -- [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/LMI2g0/5). Also, if you intended to _include_ the first/last `< >` in your match, just move those characters _inside_ the capturing group: `/[^<]*(<(?:.|[\r\n])*>).*/`

Comment: The update returns everything after `/plain...` until `...<PowerSource>0</`

Comment: Hmm. Try this: `^(?:[^<]|[\r\n])*(<(?:.|[\r\n])*>)(?:[\r\n]|[^>])*$`